# Checking if an API is monitored (hooked?)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, hook

My application uses some APIs like `GetProcAddress` and `CreateProcess` that cause sometimes antiviruses to flag it as malicious even though it is not.

What I am trying to do is check whether a specific API is being monitored or hooked and if it is then I won't call that part of the code.

How do I check whether a certain API is hooked?

This is a Windows application written in C.

Thanks.

Comment: And how would you check that your API monitor detector hasn't been hooked?

Comment: `GetProcAddress` and `CreateProcess` alone should not raise any flags for AVs. Are you doing a remote dll injection using `CreateRemoteThread`? If that's the case, the signature of your function may match the one of a malware.

Comment: No dll injection and no remote thread creation. Those 2 APIs are in different part of the programs doing different things. Do you know how to check for an API hook?

Comment: "... check whether a specific API is being... ", which API(s) are you talking about?

Comment: There is no reliable way to check whether an API has been hooked, because the person who hooked the API may also have hooked your API detector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On win32 there are no offical methods to detect and/or place hooks (besides the `SetWindowsHookEx()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990) et al functions which only cover a very small set of functionality).

Detecting a hook depends on how the hook was applied.

There are two popular methods to place a hook:

1. Import/Export table patching
2. Code overwriting

For details (pros/cons) on the different methods to place hooks please consider reading here http://help.madshi.net/ApiHookingMethods.htm.

Each method of hooking requieres a different approach to detect it.

For methods to detect hooks placed as mentioned above please look under "ApiHookCheck Algorithm" here http://www.security.org.sg/code/apihookcheck.html. There are sample sources available on this page, which I did *not* test.

Comment: The link to the ApiHookCheck Algorithm doesn't work anymore. Could someone please provide a good link to it?

Comment: @Benny: This might be a point to start: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/17904/36769

Comment: @alk thanks, I found that question as well. If it similar to the APIHookChecking algorithm you referred to, in your answer?