# In c++'s SetWindowsHookEx function

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm Korean student.
Now this is my first question after signing up.

```
DWORD getProcessId() {
    PROCESSENTRY32 process_infor;
    process_infor.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snap_handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        TH32CS_SNAPALL, //스냅 단계
        NULL //스냅할 pid
    );

    if (snap_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        Process32First(snap_handle, &process_infor);

        do {
            wchar_t* temp = process_infor.szExeFile;
            wstring ws(temp);
            string name(ws.begin(), ws.end());

            if (name == "notepad.exe") {
                cout << name << " : " << process_infor.th32ProcessID << endl;
                return process_infor.th32ProcessID;
            }

        } while (Process32Next(snap_handle, &process_infor));
    }

    CloseHandle(snap_handle);
    return FALSE;
}

BOOL inject() {
    HMODULE dll_handle;
    HOOKPROC func;
    HHOOK process_hook;

    dll_handle = LoadLibrary(L"hello.dll");
    func = (HOOKPROC) GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "injectSuccess");

    cout << "handle : " << dll_handle << endl;
    cout << "pid : " << getProcessId() << endl;

    process_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD,
        func,
        dll_handle,
        getProcessId()
    );

    cout << "pook : " << process_hook << endl;
    cout << "err : " << GetLastError() << endl;
    FreeLibrary(dll_handle);

    return FALSE;
}
```

There seems to be a problem with `SetWindowsHookEx` of the inject function in this case. The dll file loads well, and the `injectSuccess` function inside is well fetched. (I tried running it, but it worked)
And I wondered if the argument values ​​of `SetWindowsHookEx` were entered incorrectly, so I compared them and checked them continuously, but I couldn't find any difference. So, I tried `GetLastError()` with the return value of `SetWindowsHookEx` below, but the return value is 0 and the error code is 87 ("the parameter is incorrect").

So I searched, but I can't speak English well and I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; I recommend checking the result of `GetProcAddress` to be sure you actually find the function: what if it's NULL? Also, recommend you capture the last error number *immediately* after the call to `SetWindowHookEx` because subsequent calls - maybe doing the I/O - could overwrite the last error and confuse the reporting.  Doing `const DWORD err = GetLastError()` right after setting window hook captures this.

Comment: The code you posted for `getProcessId` does not take a process name ("notepad.exe"), but I think this is a typo in pasting your example.  I recommend that you check that you *actually* find a valid thread ID and check it: only call `SetWindowsHookEx` if you get a nonzero response.

Comment: Oh, I think "notepad.exe" is a typo in getProcessId. Well written with real code.

Comment: Please edit your example code so it compiles; it's clear that `getProcessId` expects to get a string parameter (`process_name`). Then we can look at it more closely.

Comment: Sorry;; It is changed. And the GetProcAddress function seems to work fine. When I manually run the thread_func() function like this, the message box appears in the window normally.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think this is right.  Where is `process_name` set in `getProcessId()`?  I recommend you get the process ID *and check the result* - maybe it is returning zero?

Comment: sorry. I edited process_name too now. And after executing the setWindowHookEx function, process_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(
WH_KEYBOARD,
func,
dll_handle,
getProcessId ("notepad.exe")
);

const DWORD err = GetLastError ();
Even if the error is immediately saved and printed, it is the same as 87.

Comment: Can you print the result of `getProcessId` to find out if it's getting an ID, or maybe it's zero?

Comment: Yes. int main() {
const DWORD result = getProcessId ("notepad.exe");
cout << "pid :"<< result << endl;
} If you output to the console like this, the 7416 is displayed fine. I checked the PID of notepad with an app called process discovery and it is the same.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a valid `func` pointer? You have to check each parameter and look for any that are obviously wrong.

Comment: The function you want to get from the dll is
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define DLLLOAD __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLLOAD __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" DLLLOAD int injectSuccess(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
 MessageBox (nullptr, L"Success (dll injection)", L"Window", MB_OK);
    return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, code, wParam, lParam);
}
is. When I run func(1, 1, 1) in the inject function like this, I get an error, but the message box runs fine.

Comment: I'm getting help from a translator, so my words can be weird. Thank you for your understanding;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`SetWindowsHookExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw):

> **dwThreadId**
>
> A handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the lpfn parameter. The hMod parameter must be set to NULL if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process.

So what `SetWindowsHookExW` needs is the thread ID, and you pass in the process ID of notepad.exe, so the parameter is wrong.

I creat a sample and test the following code:

```
BOOL inject() {
HMODULE dll_handle;
HOOKPROC func;
HHOOK process_hook;

dll_handle = LoadLibrary(L"hello.dll");
if (dll_handle) func = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "injectSuccess");
else return FALSE;
cout << "handle : " << dll_handle << endl;
cout << "pid : " << getProcessId() << endl;
HWND h = FindWindow(L"notepad", NULL);
DWORD pid;
threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, NULL);
cout << "threadID = " << threadID  << endl;
process_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_KEYBOARD,
    func,
    dll_handle,
    threadID
);

cout << "pook : " << process_hook << endl;
cout << "err : " << GetLastError() << endl;
if(dll_handle) FreeLibrary(dll_handle);
return FALSE;
}
```

This example worked for me, and you can see the difference between pid and threadID:

[image]

**Edit**

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)):

> An application installs the hook procedure by specifying the
> WH_KEYBOARD hook type and a pointer to the hook procedure in a call to
> the SetWindowsHookEx function. This hook may be called in the context
> of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message
> to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that
> installed the hook must have a message loop. So if you want to run
> this func, you need to add a message loop.

You can refer to the following code:

```
int main()
{
    inject();
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
}
```

When you press the button, the message box will pop up:

[image]

Because there are two messages for each key press and release, func is triggered twice each time.If you only want to trigger every time a button is pressed, you can modify the following code:

```
if ((0x80000000 & lParam) == 0)//This means that when the key is pressed
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Success (dll injection)", L"Window", MB_OK);
}
```

You can refer to [KeyboardProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)) to view the messages for each value in lParam.

Comment: uh! Thank you very much. This works fine and now I don't get any errors. But it runs fine and there are no errors, but the dll does not run. Why is that so? When searching with an app called Process Explorer, the dll is not in notepad.

Comment: The reason may be that Process Explorer cannot detect the linked dll. You can refer to [Checking if an API is monitored (hooked?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916539/checking-if-an-api-is-monitored-hooked).And if this origin answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Comment: So... Process Explore can't detect the dll file?
No other issues, no errors and seems to work fine, but as a result the injectSuccess doesn't seem to run.

Comment: So.... after inserting the dll into notepad, can't run it? The above modification runs as soon as the dll is loaded in main via the loadlibrary function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, almost everything seems to have been successful ^^. However, in the video above and in my code, I have a problem where the window appears twice and no other actions or output of the injectSuccess function are executed. How do I solve this problem? When this is done, I accept your post and close the question!

Comment: @user13810752 I have updated my answer.You can refer to it and [KeyboardProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85))

Comment: Wow... thank you very much. Thanks to this, everything is becoming perfect. Then maybe
if ((0x80000000 & lParam) == 0) {
        URLDownloadToFile (NULL, L "https://m.naver.com", L "C: \\ index.html", 0, NULL);
        MessageBox (nullptr, to_wstring (lParam) .c_str (), L "Window", MB_OK);
        
        return CallNextHookEx (nullptr, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
Here the message box runs fine, but the html file does not appear. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @user13810752 I think this is a new question, I suggest you close the current question and ask again, because I don't know your specific error information, you can check the return value of URLDownloadToFile to determine the error code.

Comment: ok. Thank you for your answer. I'll check your answer now.

Comment: @user13810752 Maybe you can try to add the https protocol header and change the download path, you may not have the permission under the C drive. Like `URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"https://m.naver.com", L"D:\\index.html", 0, NULL);`