# Listening to messages in another Windows app

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, windows-messages

I'd like my program to listen to messages in another Windows app.

I am aware of [SetWindowsHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but am concerned about this line:

> If the dwThreadId parameter is zero ***or specifies the identifier of a
> thread created by a different process***, the lpfn parameter **must point
> to a hook procedure in a DLL**.

I don't know which hook procedures are in Windows DLLs, so am at a loss.

(I'm using Python with ctypes to use the WinAPI.)

**Question:** How can I get my program to listen for messages in another Windows process?

Comment: This is very tricky API. In my view it is unrealistic to attempt to use it without at least a good grounding in winapi and gaining that experience through ctypes is a very suboptimal way to do it. It's far better to do that learning with a language that has more direct access to the winapi, C or C++ for instance. I recommend you do that first.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah. Point taken. Is there some other way of getting messages from a Windows app?

Comment: The Windows API surface is **huge**. Microsoft isn't exactly known to provide more than one way to accomplish any given task, to keep it somewhat manageable and maintainable. Observing messages in a different thread is done using [hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). I'm sure there are other, more involved ways to accomplish the same. Though if using hooks poses a road block, going harder is probably the wrong direction.

Comment: Hooks aren't impossible to write. It just takes time to learn the API to a sufficient level to get it right. There are no shortcuts. Think of it as though you are learning a foreign language. You might want to speak the language tomorrow, but it's gonna take a bit more time than that before you can. You can learn a bunch of words from the language very quickly, but can string together conversation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Part of the challenge in learning a new thing is that it's hard to know what one doesn't know. So far I know about messages, winprocs, and how to send messages to a window. I know about Spy++ and "inspect." I have only a hazy understanding of message queues, threads, and the innards of DLLs. What other topics are important (for hooks) that I've left out completely? Would working through Charles Petzold's "Programming Windows" give me proficiency in hooks?

Comment: "Would working through Charles Petzold's "Programming Windows" give me proficiency in hooks?" No, that won't cover hooks. But I would very much recommend that you do it, because it would give you the foundational knowledge that would allow you to subsequently learn about hooks.

Comment: "Part of the challenge in learning a new thing is that it's hard to know what one doesn't know." Can I just say how refreshing it is to come across an asker here on this site that recognises this and is keen to learn. 9 times out of 10, my comments here would have been met with, "but I need to solve this right now!" type responses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a DLL and add hook functions to the DLL.

I will use the following code in C++ to create the DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HINSTANCE hThisDLL;
HHOOK hMsgHook;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    hThisDLL = hinstDLL;
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //do what you want to do
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL InstallHook()
{
    if (!hMsgHook)
        hMsgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, &GetMsgProc, hThisDLL, 0);
    return (hMsgHook != NULL);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) VOID UninstallHook()
{
    if (hMsgHook)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMsgHook);
        hMsgHook = NULL;
    }
}
```

After generating the `.dll` file, you can load the dynamic library through the [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryw) function, and use the [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) function to get the function address in the dynamic library. Then call the hook function.

Here is the code with C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* LPInstallHook)();
typedef VOID(WINAPI* LPUninstallHook)();
int main()
{
    HMODULE dll_handle;
    LPInstallHook installProc;
    LPUninstallHook uninstallProc;
    HHOOK process_hook;
    dll_handle = LoadLibrary(L"test.dll");
    if (dll_handle)
    {
        installProc = (LPInstallHook)GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "InstallHook");
        uninstallProc = (LPUninstallHook)GetProcAddress(dll_handle, "UninstallHook");
    }
    MSG msg;
    installProc();
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    uninstallProc();

    if(dll_handle) FreeLibrary(dll_handle);
}
```

This is part of the code implemented in python, you can refer to it:

```
import ctypes
import os
from ctypes import *

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dllpath = os.path.join(path,"test.dll")
    pDll = ctypes.WinDLL(dllpath)
    pDll.InstallHook()
    msg = ctypes.wintypes.MSG()
    while user32.GetMessageW(ctypes.byref(msg), 0, 0, 0) != 0:
        user32.TranslateMessage(msg)
        user32.DispatchMessageW(msg)
```

Of course, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN), you can set `dwThreadId` as the identifier of other threads. You can refer to the similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492788/in-cs-setwindowshookex-function/64493572#64493572).

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.